# Batch Script breakline on spaces?

Tags: string, batch-file

I'm using the following piece of code; to change something in a Cmakefile:

```
for /f %%j in (CMakeLists.txt) do (
 if "%%j"=="Extensions_AntTweakBar" (
  echo #Extensions_AntTweakBar >> temp.tmp 
 ) else (
  if "%%j"=="Extensions_Inspection" (
   echo #Extensions_Inspection >> temp.tmp
  ) else (
      if "%%j"=="Extensions_InspectionBar" (
    echo #Extensions_InspectionBar >> temp.tmp
   ) else (
    echo %%j >> temp.tmp
   )
  )
 )
)
```

It seems to work, that is, it does change the selected lines, however, if theres a space on one line, it only gets that line till the space occurs. 
Example:

```
SET( PROJECT_NAME "MyProject")
```

Only gets the string:

```
SET(
```

How am I supposed to get the full string then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you append a space at each line.

```
echo %%j[space]>> temp.tmp
```

Here you can remove it(works only with %%j), but normally it is better to set the redirection as prefix, like

```
>> temp.tmp echo %%j
```

With a normal variable the postfix variant could fail

```
set var=hallo2
echo %var%>temp.tmp
```

Expands to echo hallo2>temp.tmp or echo hallo 2> temp.tmp, so only the stderr would redirected.
The next problem are the keywords **ON OFF /?**, if your file contains such a word you get unexpected results, because the **echo** interprets these words.

**[EDIT:] To solve this you can use *echo(***

```
>>temp.tmp echo(%%j
```

You can get empty lines (or lines with only whitespaces), you simply need to prefix them.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n ".*" qut.bat') do (
    set var=%%a
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!var:*:=!
    endlocal
)
```

The toggling of the DelayedExpansion is neccessary to preserve "!" and "^" characters

Comment: I'll try to look into that :)

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiters are space and tab. If you override the default delimiter, it should read the entire line with spaces in between

```
for /f "delims=@" %%j in (CMakeLists.txt) do
```

I set it to @, and it ignores space as delimiter and reads the entire line. You can set it a unique character that you know will not be in the text file.

Comment: I do kinda love you right now, however it doesn't get empty lines?

Comment: @Skeen: Empty lines are *always* skipped with `for`. You have no way of dealing with them in batch files (at least not that I know of). Eric: if you do `"delims=@"` only to have no actual delimiter you might as well use `"delims="` to the same effect – and you don't need to think of a character that doesn't appear in the input.